# Remove last n elements of a vec, by chunks

Tags: rust

Having a `vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]` I would like to remove, in chunks of 6 elements, the last 3 elements, so the result would be a slice or vec like `[1,2,3,7,8,9]`. Is there an easy way of doing that without intermediate allocations (like collecting small vecs), preferably using iterators?
Thanks!

Comment: I thought of something like this, but I don't know collecting inside map is very efficient.
`let a: Vec<_> = v.chunks_exact(6).map(|x| x.iter().take(3).collect::<Vec<_>>()).flatten().collect();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just filter based on the index (which you can get with `.enumerate()`)

```rs
fn main() {
    let data = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
    let new_data: Vec<i32> = data.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .filter(|(i, _)| (*i / 3) % 2 == 0)
        .map(|(_, v)| *v) // you could have this be Vec<&i32>, but I don't think you'd save memory/time. if it was a more complex data type, references would save memory and time
        .collect();
    println!("{new_data:?}");
}
```

`0 / 3 == 0`, `0 % 2 == 0`, ? `0 == 0` -> `true` so keep
`1 / 3 == 0`, `0 % 2 == 0`, ? `0 == 0` -> `true` so keep
`2 / 3 == 0`, `0 % 2 == 0`, ? `0 == 0` -> `true` so keep
`3 / 3 == 1`, `1 % 2 == 1`, ? `1 == 0` -> `false` so skip
`4 / 3 == 1`, `1 % 2 == 1`, ? `1 == 0` -> `false` so skip
`5 / 3 == 1`, `1 % 2 == 1`, ? `1 == 0` -> `false` so skip
`6 / 3 == 2`, `2 % 2 == 0`, ? `0 == 0` -> `true` so keep
...

Comment: Thanks!
I actually just found out about flat_map:
`let a: Vec<_> = v.chunks_exact(6).flat_map(|x| x.iter().take(3)).collect();`

Comment: If you don't need the original Vec unaffected, this would be best written with [`retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain).

Comment: @daniellga you should add that and the comment on your question as an answer, neither is a good comment, both are valid answers.